# Converting a formatted date to epoches in PHP

Tags: php, date

Many moons ago, it was decided that timestamps would be stored in an SQL table like so:

```
date ("Y-m-d_H-i-s")
```

This would produce a timestamp looking like `2017-02-04_00-37-45`.

Time has moved on, and it has got to the point where I need to be able to manipulate this data, sorting out how many rows were created in the month January etc and so I need to convert the timestamps over to epoches.

The table has ~1000 rows and I intend on using PHP for the job.

```
strtotime($row["time"]);
```

returns empty and

```
$date = new DateTime($time);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d_H-i-s");
```

simply provides this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2017-02-03_09-41-42) at position 10 (_): Unexpected character

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format isn't recognized by `strtotime()` or other functions which expects a given format, because you use underscores instead of spaces, and dashes between your hour/minute/seconds. You can however use the `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to create from a specific format, which would create the DateTime object from what you have.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d_H-i-s", $row["time"]);
```

- http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks!